# Paquete para hacer migracion inversa en Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql

Quiero saber si existe algun paquete que me permita crear los migrate de mi base de datos en postgresql en Laravel 5.6 y si es así como usarlo.

**Edit1:** La base de datos ya se encuentra creada, la idea es generar los archivos migrate en base a esa base de datos.

**EDIT2:** Encontre el siguiente paquete:
https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator
Lo que me genero la siguiente duda: ¿Se pueden crear schemas con el migrate asi como se crean las tablas?

Comment: No es necesario un paquete, solo configura el .env de laravel

Comment: De hecho el comando  make:migration está disponible luego de configurar laravel.

Comment: Como configurar?@Shassain
@Jakala se que se puede, creo que no me explique bien. Ya tengo una base de datos, quiero generar los migrate de esa base de datos ya creada

Comment: de hecho si es necesario un paquete externo por que el trata de hacer las migraciones(los archivos) directo de una base de datos que ya tiene hecha y que fe construida sin Laravel

Comment: Exactamente @AlfredoPaz, Aunque creo que no me supe explicar bien en mi pregunta.

Comment: dame un momento y te comparto un package para eso